# Adobe AIR 1.5 - Package AIR installer as a native Windows Executable (.EXE)

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air, executable

Hello StackOverflow community,

Is there any way to package the installer for an Adobe AIR application using Adobe AIR 1.5 as an executable (.EXE) file?

I found that this is possible for Adobe AIR 2.0, but it requires an upgrade to Adobe AIR 2.0 runtime. Are there any other options using the Adobe AIR 1.5 runtime?

Thanks,
Mauricio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the program to redistribute the AIR Runtime.

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_agreement.html

I believe joining the program also provides you additional information about installing the AIR app and possibly the AIR runtime silently.

I think if you execute an AIR program with the '-silent' attribute you will get a silent install.  Something similar at one point worked, at least, and I'm not sure of the exact command line argument.

Once you have those to things in place, it should be easy to launch the AIR runtime and/or AIR App installer from your own executable installer.  There should be plenty of programs for creating the installer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Flextras. We are currently going forward with the silent installer method.
Do you know what benefits / packaging you get by joining the program to redistribute the AIR runtime?

Comment: If you join the program to redistribute the AIR Runtime then you can legally redistribute the AIR Runtime.  You can have your own installer install AIR if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be done with the silent install method and a bit of scripting.  If you needed to install the runtime at the same time you would need to sign up for the AIR Runtime Distribution agreement.  I'm not sure what benefit you would gain over the normal AIR installation tho.

Comment: One benefit would be the ability to do a silent install of the application and/or runtime.  In some situations that would be desired by a client.  Another benefit is to include other things in the installer (Such as Merapi or other independent programs).

Comment: Good point, although worth pointing out that Merapi et al are unsupported by Adobe in 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Nope, AIR 2.0 only.

Answer (score -2):

No. There is no known way to package an Adobe AIR application as a native executable installer. You would have to do it with the .air package installation only, if you want AIR 1.5.

Comment: This is not completely correct; You can license the AIR Runtime for redistribution; and wrap up the AIR Application and AIR Runtime installer into your own installer which could easily be an executable.